# Can't install Phalcon extention on Ubuntu

Tags: php

I'm trying to install [Phalcon](http://phalconphp.com) frameworks and I can't get this part done right

> 2. Add the extension to your php.ini:
>
>    `extension=phalcon.so`
> 3. Finally, restart the webserver

I've changed my `php.ini` file located at `/etc/php5/apache2/` restart the `apache` server but the extension is not added when I test it through

```
<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => zlib
    [7] => bcmath
    [8] => bz2
    [9] => calendar
    [10] => ctype
    [11] => dba
    [12] => dom
    [13] => hash
    [14] => fileinfo
    [15] => filter
    [16] => ftp
    [17] => gettext
    [18] => SPL
    [19] => iconv
    [20] => mbstring
    [21] => session
    [22] => posix
    [23] => Reflection
    [24] => standard
    [25] => shmop
    [26] => SimpleXML
    [27] => soap
    [28] => sockets
    [29] => Phar
    [30] => exif
    [31] => sysvmsg
    [32] => sysvsem
    [33] => sysvshm
    [34] => tokenizer
    [35] => wddx
    [36] => xml
    [37] => xmlreader
    [38] => xmlwriter
    [39] => zip
    [40] => apache2handler
    [41] => PDO
    [42] => curl
    [43] => gd
    [44] => imagick
    [45] => imap
    [46] => intl
    [47] => json
    [48] => mcrypt
    [49] => memcache
    [50] => ming
    [51] => mysql
    [52] => mysqli
    [53] => pdo_mysql
    [54] => pdo_sqlite
    [55] => pspell
    [56] => readline
    [57] => recode
    [58] => snmp
    [59] => sqlite3
    [60] => tidy
    [61] => xmlrpc
    [62] => xsl
    [63] => mhash
    [64] => Zend OPcache
)
```

`phalcon` extension is nowhere.

I even tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/431740/phalcon-doesnt-load).

Comment: Do you have any error message? any log? please explain the situation in more detail

Comment: @PatomaS What more I need to say? I'm trying to install `Phalcon` taking the steps http://phalconphp.com/en/download , I'm trying to see the extentions but `extension=phalcon.so` is not mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

I did the setup via following these steps...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make php5-mysql git-core autoconf

### Do these in any folder you want
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install

### Create the extension ini file in /etc/php5/mods-available    
echo 'extension=phalcon.so' | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini
cd /etc/php5/mods-available    
sudo php5enmod phalcon

### Restart apache
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked through it, I used nginx + php-fpm instead, but the workflow should be the same. Create a file in `/etc/php5/mods-available` called `phalcon.ini`:

```
echo 'extension=phalcon.so' | sudo tee -a /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini
```

Now create a symbolic link to this file (note: I'm doing it the right way, instead of dumping the file directly) in `/etc/php5/conf.d/`:

```
sudo ln -s -T ../mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini
```

Restart your webserver (and fpm if you have it) and voila!

> Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre [6] => zlib [7] => bcmath [8] => bz2 [9] => calendar [10] => ctype [11] => dba [12] => dom [13] => hash [14] => fileinfo [15] => filter [16] => ftp [17] => gettext [18] => SPL [19] => iconv [20] => json [21] => mbstring [22] => session [23] => posix [24] => Reflection [25] => standard [26] => shmop [27] => SimpleXML [28] => soap [29] => sockets [30] => Phar [31] => exif [32] => sysvmsg [33] => sysvsem [34] => sysvshm [35] => tokenizer [36] => wddx [37] => xml [38] => xmlreader [39] => xmlwriter [40] => zip [41] => cgi-fcgi [42] => PDO [43] => gd [44] => mysql [45] => mysqli [46] => pdo_mysql [47] => pdo_pgsql [48] => pgsql [49] => mcrypt **[50] => phalcon** [51] => mhash )

Comment: Worked for me with nginx and php5-fpm, the only change I had to make was to the symbolic link commmand:  `sudo ln -s -T /etc/php5/mods-available/phalcon.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-phalcon.ini` (added the "fpm" subdirectory) - thanks!